# How to properly use 'return' in a firebase cloud function when performing multiple actions against documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to understand how to properly use a cloud function..

The cloud function below a**chieves the desired result, however, I am not using a 'return' in it.**

is this an issue? if yes, how do I solve it?

```
exports.onJobChangeToClosedAndSubstateIsCancelled = functions.firestore
    .document("job/{docId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, eventContext) => {
        const afterSnapData = change.after.data();
        const afterJobState = afterSnapData["Job state"];
        const afterJobSubState = afterSnapData["Job substate"];

        if (afterJobSubState == "Cancelled" && afterJobState == "Closed") {

            // get all job related job applications
            const relatedJobApplicationsList = await admin.firestore().collection("job application").where("Job id", "==", change.before.id).get();
            // mark job applications closed so that other contractors cant waste their time
            relatedJobApplicationsList.forEach(async doc => {

                await admin.firestore().collection("job application").doc(doc.id).update({
                    "Job application state": "Closed",
                    "Job application substate": "Job cancelled by client",
                })

            })


        }
    });
```

My understanding from other questions such as the one below is that I should be returning the change on the document or the action taking place. ( is this correct? )
[Can you help me?-firebase-function-onUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58281554/can-you-help-me-firebase-function-onupdate)

Below is an example of a cloud function where I was able to place the 'return' statement:

```
// when a chat message is created
// send a notification to the user who is on the other side of the chat
// update the chat 'Chat last update' so that the Chats screen can put the chat at the top of the page
exports.onChatMessageCreate = functions.firestore
    .document("chat messages/{docId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const snapData = snapshot.data();
        // information about who sent the message
        const senderUserName = snapData["Chat message creator first name"];
        const senderUserId = snapData["User id"];
        // chat id to which chat messages belong to
        const chatId = snapData["Chat id"];

        // information about who should receive the message
        let receiverUserId;
        let receiverToken = "";

        // fetch user to send message to
        const chatData = await (await admin.firestore().collection("chat").doc(chatId).get()).data();
        const chatUsersData = chatData["User ids list"];

        chatUsersData[0] == senderUserId ? receiverUserId = chatUsersData[1] : receiverUserId = chatUsersData[0];

        receiverToken = await (await admin.firestore().collection("user token").doc(receiverUserId).get()).data()["token"];

        console.log("admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()::   " + admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

        // set chat last update
        await admin.firestore().collection("chat").doc(chatId).update({
            "Chat last update": admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: senderUserName,
                body: snapData["Chat message"],
                sound: "default",
            },
            data: {
                click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                message: "Sample Push Message",
            },
        };

        return await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(receiverToken, payload);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this an issue?

Yes, by not returning a Promise (or a value since your callback function is `async`) you are incorrectly managing the life cycle of your Cloud Function.

In your case, since you have an if block, the easiest is to just do `return null;` (or `return 0;` or `return;`) at the end of the CF as follows.

In addition, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) since you want to execute a variable number of calls to an asynchronous method in parallel.

```
exports.onJobChangeToClosedAndSubstateIsCancelled = functions.firestore
    .document("job/{docId}")
    .onUpdate(async (change, eventContext) => {
        const afterSnapData = change.after.data();
        const afterJobState = afterSnapData["Job state"];
        const afterJobSubState = afterSnapData["Job substate"];

        if (afterJobSubState == "Cancelled" && afterJobState == "Closed") {

            // get all job related job applications
            const relatedJobApplicationsList = await admin.firestore().collection("job application").where("Job id", "==", change.before.id).get();
            
            // mark job applications closed so that other contractors cant waste their time
            const promises = [];

            relatedJobApplicationsList.forEach(doc => {

                promises.push(admin.firestore().collection("job application").doc(doc.id).update({
                    "Job application state": "Closed",
                    "Job application substate": "Job cancelled by client",
                }));

            })

            await Promise.all(promises);
        }
        
        return null;
    });
```

---

More info on how to properly manage CF life cycle [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) in the doc.

You may also be interested by [watching the talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzEcq8_3eD0&t=2752s) I gave at the [I/O Extended UK & Ireland event](https://gdg.community.dev/events/details/google-gdg-london-presents-io-extended-uk-ireland-july-27-29/) in 2021. This talk was specifically dedicated to this subject.